# Pattern matching with [x,_] syntax vs (x:_) for infinite lists in haskell

Tags: haskell

I expected these definitions of a function getting the second element in a list to be the same

```
let myFunction (a:(b:_)) = b
```

```
let myFunction [a,b,_] = b
```

... but the second one doesn't work for infinite lists

```
Prelude> let myFunction [a,b,_] = b
Prelude> myFunction [1..] 
*** Exception: <interactive>:8:5-26: Non-exhaustive patterns in function myFunction
```

What's the difference?

Edit: maybe `[a,b,_]` expands to `(a:(b:(_:[])))`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`[x,_]` only matches a list with *exactly* two elements. Likewise, `[a,b,_]` matches any list with exactly three elements, putting the first element in `a`, the second element in `b` and discarding the third. `(x:_)`, on the other hand, matches any list with *at least one* element, putting the first element in `x` and discarding the rest.

`(:)` is the list constructor. All non-empty lists are composed of calls to `(:)`. Note that `[a,b,c]` is syntactic sugar for `a : (b : (c : []))`.